# Отправка заявок на почту идет в папку "Спам"

Tags: php, javascript

Сделал демо версию магазина с возможностью отправки заявок на товары. в yandex.почта письмо приходит во "входящие", а в mail.ru и gmail в папку "спам". Помогите понять в чем причина?

p.s. На php не работаю, код написан по видеоуроку, собственноручно. php-код выглядит так:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

//читать json файл
$json = file_get_contents( '../goods.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

//письмо
$message = '';
$message .= '<h1>Заказ в магазине</h1>';
$message .='<p>Телефон:  '.$_POST['ephone'].'</p>';
$message .='<p>Почта:  '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
$message .='<p>Клиент:  '.$_POST['ename'].'</p>';


$cart = $_POST['cart'];
$sum = 0;
foreach ($cart as $id=>$count) {
  $message .=$json[$id]['name'].' --- ';
  $message .=$count.' --- ';
  $message .=$count*$json[$id]['cost'];
  $message .='<br>';
  $sum = $sum + $count*$json[$id]['cost'];
}
$message .='Всего: '.$sum;
//print_r($message);

$to = 'mirosloft@gmail.com'.',';
$to .=$_POST['email'];
$specttext = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Заказ</title></head><body>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

$m = mail($to, 'Заказ в магазине', $specttext.$message.'</body></html>', $headers);
if ($m) {echo 1;} else {echo 0;}

?>
```

Comment: Причин может быть несколько, но скорее всего просто для GMAIL ваш айпишник (с которого вы отправляете письма) - является не доверенным. P.S. Дело не в коде.

Comment: Попробуйте слать письмо без html обвертки, т.к. "излишняя красота" - один из признаков спама. Возможно слово "магазин" не нравится...

Comment: @nick_n_a Вы имеете ввиду убрать здесь '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Заказ</title></head><body>'  тег <html></html> ?

Comment: Да, убрать теги,а текст оставить. И выставить соответственно Content-type: text/plain;

Comment: А чем отправляете почту? и от кого?

Comment: @nick_n_a вы говорите "тегИ" , имеете ввиду все теги? или только <html> </html> ?

Comment: Все теги. Перевод строки `\n` текст не пострадает в вашем случае.

Comment: DKIM, SPF, DMARC настроены и проверены?

Comment: @andreymal я не знаю что это) в вопросе указал спецально, что не работал с php до этого никогда)

Comment: @RafaelShepard какой механизм для отправки почты использует сервер? `sendmail` например?  
В общем письмо в спам может уходить по причине того, что письмо отправленное  с info@magazin.ru, на самом деле отправлено с вашего сервера, который подменил имя отправителя. 
Вот статья на хабре которая вам должна помочь понять этот момент  https://habr.com/post/322616/
Хотя....я могу быть и не прав. =)

Comment: @RafaelShepard php тут ни при чём, но если не настроено, то вот и ответ

Comment: @nick_n_a не сработало)

Comment: @RafaelShepard попробуйте скачать библиотеку PHPMailer и в ней разобраться. У меня для рассылки на почты вызывается именно эта библиотека, и пока проблем небыло.